# Is it possible to have two tooltip object independently in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have created a fiddle to showcase the need -

https://jsfiddle.net/guestMe/orL5txs0/74/

The example fiddle consists of below things-
1.A testTooltip, created in chart load event.

```
   this.testTooltip = new Highcharts.Tooltip(this, this.options.tooltip);
```

2. A draggable plot line in load event
3. On moving draggable plot line, if it intersects on point, it display tooltip

const points = chart.series .map(x => x.searchPoint(e, true)).filter(x => !!x && x.category !== null)

```
    if (points.length) {
        chart.testTooltip.refresh(points)
    }
      draggablePlotLine.attr({
        x: e.chartX
      })
    }
```

Indepdently both tooltip works, if we hover on any point it shows tooltip or if we drag blue line on any point it shows the tooltip..

What i need help in fixing is , can both tooltip be displayed ...

The dragged line tooltip not to hide, and hover should behave as it is ..

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly. You want to add another separate tooltip for dragged line, right? Because now I don't see the difference if lines 51 and 79 are commented out or not.

Comment: Yes.. exactly :)